# Adding a Breakdown Dimension to a Pivot table on Google Data Studio

Tags: pivot-table, looker-studio

I am using a pivot table on Google Data Studio, which shows total income for each month of the year. 
I wish to show total income for each month of the year, separated by years - for example, January 2017, and January 2018 will hopefully appear one above the other. 
I attached an example that describes best what I need (couldn't find an explanation for how its built in the picture)
In the picture, the equivalent for "Years" is "Gender"

[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out. its just by adding another metric in the row dimension, missed it on the first try..